# Getting the response after a survey using Qualtrics Webservice

Tags: web-services, drupal-7, qualtrics

I am using qualtrics for embedding survey in my website. My requirement is to get the email from qualtrics at end of the survey and send it back to my website as a response.I have seen the web service option in qualtrics and planning to put the web service at the end of the survey flow.I have already read the documentation and noticed that we need to pass a feed url as a web service url. Please suggest a good documentation regarding this.

Note: I am using  website which is running on Drupal 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a web service to send data to and/or retrieve data from your website.

To send data from the survey to your website, you pass each piece of data as a parameter.  Just as you would in a url, except Qualtrics takes care of the encoding for you.

To retrieve data from your website and store it as embedded data in your survey, the web service must format it as json or an xml feed (rss or atom).

If you only need to send and not receive data from the web service, click the fire and forget checkbox.

For general information you can look here:
http://www.qualtrics.com/university/researchsuite/advanced-building/survey-flow/web-service/

Comment: Thanks @T. Gibbons. I have created a webservice and i am playing with that now. I am creating a question for email in the survey and trying to call the service with the params(piped text code of email question).